# What's wrong when a particle is accelerating?

Tags: calculus

This is surely a dumb question, calculus isn't probably inconsistent - but I can't guess the flaw.

Suppose a ball is at rest. Except position, all other derivatives of it is zero.  When I hit it, the position is changing, so there is a velocity; the velocity has gone from zero to nonzero, so there is acceleration; and crazily enough the acceleration has gone from zero to nonzero, so it is changing too (ad infinitum).

One portion is a physics question, that there should be no terms higher than acceleration, I am not asking that. I am asking if I expand the position from its taylor series just before the hit, everything is zero all the time, but it is actually not. Why?

Comment: This is the tool we use to describe an idealized "hit": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Answer (score 5):

Your "mistake" is here:

> if I expand the position from its taylor series

The function that describes the movement of the ball is **zero** for times, smaller than $t_0$, and **nonzero** for times larger than $t_0$. This is only possible if the function s *not analytic*, which means that the function either does not have, or is not equal to, its Taylor series.

---

There's nothing strange about this. For example, you can look at the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac1{t}} & x>0\\ 0& x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

which is a **continuous, infinitely differentiable** function. The Taylor series for this function around $0$ is equal to $0$, but the function itself is not equal to $0$.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but maybe it's possible to hit the ball in a soft way such that $x(t)$ is actually analytic...have to think more about it.

Comment: Ok, no, it's not possible. +1

Comment: @marcotrevi No, it isn't possible. You must understand that the Taylor series is only guaranteed to work *locally* even for analytic functions. If the function is locally $0$, then the series is $0$.

Comment: Yes, I realized it as well. Thanks!